# What is best book on self-adjoint extensions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations

I need to understand self-adjoint extensions in quantum mechanics to solve some problems of scattering and bound states in Aharonov-Bohm potentials. There are some referencies that present the math concepts in a more friendly way for someone with a physics background as myself? And I would like to see more applications on the resolutions of problems for better understanding. Any suggestions?

Comment: The book "Mathematical Methods in Quantum Mechanics, With Applications to Schrödinger Operators" by Gerald Teschl is probably a good choice.

Comment: Also the book "Sturm-Liouville Theory" by Anton Zettl would have a wealth of material on self-adjoint extensions and their relation to the choice of boundary conditions, on more manageable 1d or ODE-like problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned this subject by reading  "Principles of Advanced Mathematical Physics, Vol. 1" by Robert D. Richtmyer.  This is a great book for filling in the gaps in math knowlege left by the traditional undergraduate math-for-physics course. Richtmeyer was a  down-to-earth  computational physicist and there is nothing in this book that is there just for mathematics sake. Everything   has applications to real-world physics settings, but ones where more sophistication (eg self-adjoint extensions) is needed.

For a less sophisticated and simpler account of why extensions are sometimes required, and how you figure out what they are,  you can try chapter 4 in "Mathematics for Physics: A guided tour for graduate students" by myself and Paul Goldbart  (our book is publsihed by CUP, but a freely-available   draft version is available [here](https://goldbart.gatech.edu/PostScript/MS_PG_book/bookmaster.pdf).) but I still recommend Richtmeyer.